# OpenCV3.2 compilation error MAC OS X

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I have been trying to install OpenCV but whenever i complete the installation phase, linking libraries and headers a linking error pops up..

The final error was it couldn't find -lopencv_ts, i am new to the OpenCV world so what is the use of this library?!

And the only option left to me to compile OpenCV source codes is to delete -lopencv_ts from the "other linking Flags" in Xcode

Why am i worrying.. because the school project that i'm going to work on is related to do streaming and compression.. Does lopencv_ts library related to this?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/60142/what-is-opencv_ts/), `opencv_ts` is a test library, so you would be fine without it in your project.